# Why can't I see the query parameters in the form present in the url?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem getting the form values by passing the two query parameters, id and type, from the url.

Let's assume the URL is:

... page.html?id=14&type=Title

I want the values of these to be shown in the form to then make the change later.

```js
function getQueryVariable () {
             var query = window.location.search.substring (1);
             var vars = query.split ("&");
             for (var i = 0; i <vars.length; i ++) {
                 var pair = vars [i] .split ("=");
             }
         }

         function onLoad () {
             var value = getQueryVariable ();
             var id = document.getElementById ('id');
             var type = document.getElementById ('type');
             id.value = value;
             type.value = value;
         }
```

```html
<div class = "container">
         <form method ="post" id="save" action="javascript: myFunction()" onload="onLoad()">
             <div class = "field">
                 <label for = "id"> ID: </label>
                 <input type = "number" id = "id" name = "id" />
             </div>
             <div class = "field">
                 <label for = "type"> Fragment Type: </label>
                 <input type = "text" id = "type" name = "type" />
             </div>
             <div class = "field">
                 <button type = "submit" class = "full"> Save changes </button>
             </div>
         </form>
     </div>
```

As you can see from the code, I call the onLoad() function to load the data into the form.

I don't get any errors; the values of the getQueryVariable() function variables are correct, but I notice that it is not called.

myFunction() is not shown, but this is the function that will serve me later to modify the fields of the form.

Could you kindly help me?

Comment: `getQueryVariable()` doesn't return anything. And the content of the loop doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: If `getQueryVariable()` would return something useful, then you would store that one value in all input fields. So `onLoad()` also doesn't make that much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to execute onLoad function,
then you need to create an object to store the values and pass it to another function.
And your loop is really out of the world, I corrected it, please try to understand my code and if you have questions feel free to comment.
Here you go, for query, I changed it to a string that you provided as an exemple, so it would work in snippet.

```js
function getQueryVariable () {
     var object = {}
     var query = "id=14&type=Hello%20Title";
     var vars = query.split ("&");
     for (var i = 0; i <vars.length; i ++) {
         let splitted = vars[i].split('=')
         object[splitted[0]] = decodeURI(splitted[1])
     }
     return object;
 }

 function onLoad () {
     var pairs = getQueryVariable ();
     var id = document.getElementById ('id');
     var type = document.getElementById ('type');
     id.value = pairs.id;
     type.value = pairs.type;
 }
        
  onLoad();
```

```html
<div class = "container">
         <form method ="post" id="save" action="javascript: myFunction()" onload="onLoad()">
             <div class = "field">
                 <label for = "id"> ID: </label>
                 <input type = "number" id = "id" name = "id" />
             </div>
             <div class = "field">
                 <label for = "type"> Fragment Type: </label>
                 <input type = "text" id = "type" name = "type" />
             </div>
             <div class = "field">
                 <button type = "submit" class = "full"> Save changes </button>
             </div>
         </form>
     </div>
```

Comment: since I have a title like `"Hello%20title"` so with `%20` how can I change the code so that `%20` doesn't appear?

Comment: This is called URI, I edited the post and added the "Hello20%title" as type variable, and added decodeURI function that's desinged to decode the URI, if you liked my answer, please to vote it up.

Comment: perfect, thank you infinitely.

Answer (score -1):

Your `getQueryVariable ()` function is not returning anything. You can try something like this:

```
function getQueryVariable () {
             var query = window.location.search.substring (1);
             var vars = query.split ("&");
             var params = {}
             for (var i = 0; i <vars.length; i ++) {
                 var pair = vars [i] .split ("=");
                 params[pair[0]] = pair[1]
             }
             return params
         }

         function onLoad () {
             var params = getQueryVariable ();
             var id = document.getElementById ('id');
             var type = document.getElementById ('type');
             id.value = params.id ;
             type.value = params.type ;
         }
```